# Can I use props in a styled component written with this syntax?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-props, styling

There is this example on how to create a custom slider component
using material ui in react. The styled component definition is the following:

```
 const PrettoSlider = styled((props) => <Slider {...props} />)({
  height: 8,
  "& .MuiSlider-track": {
    color: "red",
  },
  ... (some more style properties) ...
});
```

Then this component is used as follows:

```
<PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto"/>
```

And this works fine, however, now I'd like to change the styles of the styled component for multiple instances, like:

```
<PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" color="red"/>
<PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" color="blue"/>
<PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" color="green"/>
```

How can I pass additional properties ("color" in this case) so I can use it
in the styled css definitions, i.e., replacing **color: "red",** for **PrettoSlider** with something like **color: props.color,**? I tried it e.g., by changing

```
styled((props) => <Slider {...props} />)({
```

to

```
styled((props) => <Slider {...props} />)((props) => {
```

However, using Typescript, it says that for *props* the type *Theme* was expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this syntax

```
const Container = styled.div<{color: string}>`
  color: ${props => props.color};
`
```

If a lot of properties depend on the prop such as being in dark mode:
Import the css from styled components.

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';
```

Then use is like:

```
const Container = styled.div<{isDarkMode: boolean}>`
  ${props =>
     props.isDarkMode
       ? css`...All properties for dark mode here`
       : css`...All properties for normal mode here`
   }
`
```